# Desoldered Resistors on rotary encoder breakout can I just short them togather

Tags: arduino, pcb, breakout

Someone gave me this rotary encoder breakout, but they unsoldered the SMT resistors for some other project. Now I don't have any SMT resistors on hand and can't justify buying a roll of them. So would it be all right if I just shorted those pads together?

[image: The Breakout Board]

I know that this rotary encoder came from sunfounder and that the resistors were 10K. Based on the PCB layout I can't tell if they were essential or not.

[image: Traces Drawn]

In the picture, above I drew where the traces go as far as I can go. The main reason I'm asking is they appear to connect across the traces.

Comment: Have you got a schematic for the breakout board and/or the datasheet for the encoder?  Can you ask the man who gave you the board why he had removed the resistors in the first place?  Do you understand what the resistors are for (myself, I can only guess)?  Welcome to EE.SE, by the way.

Comment: @NickAlexeev He removed them because he need a couple of 10k SMT resistors for a project (trying to hack a battery power supply for a beaglebone). They were the only SMTs he could find, and the rotary encoder wasn't important to the project. I just looked on the encoder for a model number and I can't find one.

Comment: Digikey sells these in quantities as low as 1 for 10 cents each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a terrible photo!

It's likely that the resistors were being used as pullups against the contact closures of the encoder. If that's the case, you need to replace them. Shorting them out would connect all of the contacts directly to the supply (and to each other).

Or you could simply leave them off, and provide the pullup function elsewhere in your system.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with them. Any MCU or GPIO chip made in the past decade should have internal pullups.

Comment: Now wait, I've looked the PCB traces and they the 2 resistors going vertical appear to be pulling to another trace, and the one going horizontal contacts another trace to the 2 pull-ups on that trace. Wouldn't the missing resistors cause a break in the circuit on the actual pcb?

Comment: @HSchmale: Yes, but that isn't a problem. The encoder itself connects the outputs to ground, and the internal pullups can handle pulling them high.

Comment: I tested the rotary encoder last night and it works with out the resistors. They were just pullups for the push button switch built in to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the pads are large enough you may be able to solder some 1/4 watt resistors to them. Otherwise you can purchase surface mount resistor in small quantities on ebay at a very reasonable price. Shorting the components could have an adverse effect, depending on how you use the device.